# Generate objects individually from variables

Tags: makefile, target

I'm doing a `Makefile` to make objects with the same `gcc` command. This file looks like this:

```
SRCLIB = main.c srv.c
OBJLIB = main.o srv.o
CC = gcc
CCFLAGS = -Wall -Werror

$(OBJLIB) : $(SRCLIB)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

The objetive is to execute this like:

```
gcc -Wall -c read_line.c -o read_line.o
gcc -Wall -c client.c -o client.o
```

But I don't know how to do it, and everything I tested is not working. Is it even possible to do this in a `Makefile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your makefile expands to this, after the variables are expanded:

```
main.o srv.o : main.c srv.c
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

In make, using multiple targets in explicit rules like this is the same as writing the rule multiple times, once for each target.  So, this is the same as this:

```
main.o : main.c srv.c
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
srv.o : main.c srv.c
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
```

This means that if either of the source files changes, BOTH object files will be recreated (since each object depends on both sources, not just their own source file).

Further, in your compile line you use the variable `$^` which expands to all the prerequisites.  So your compile lines will expand to:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -c main.c srv.c -o main.o
gcc -Wall -Werror -c main.c srv.c -o srv.o
```

which is illegal: if you use `-c` with the `-o` option you can only compile one source file.

Make has built-in rules that already know how to compile files, so there's no need to write your own.  You can just write this:

```
SRCLIB = main.c srv.c
OBJLIB = main.o srv.o
CC = gcc
CCFLAGS = -Wall -Werror

.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJLIB)
```

and that's all you need.

Comment: You're just right, that was my problem. I did what you said and it worked like a charm, thank you!